# About Twitter's REST API 1.1 Bad Authentication data Code : 215

Tags: json, twitter

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=20.9533951,75.9364752&radius=500&types=food&key=put_your_key_here

This is the URL of google maps api. Which returns json data if we pass the key at the last. and hit that url from our browser directly.
So is there anything like that in twitter as well? By which we can pass our consumer key or something like that at the end of link like this https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/available.json
Because without any tokens if we hit this URL then its giving error : Bad Authentication data Code : 215

Please help me. i am finding this from very long and have no luck.
Please Thank You So Much.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is that all requests to the Twitter REST API need to be authenticated using OAUTH.  You need to follow the OAUTH process and use the tokens as described starting [here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/introduction).

Answer (score 0):

```
&oauth_consumer_key= your consumer key
&oauth_nonce=nonce
&oauth_signature_method=HMACSHA1
&oauth_timestamp=1505894968
&oauth_token=token
&oauth_version=1.0
&oauth_signature=signature
```

You have to send these header with your request then it will work fine